# ASP.NET MVC 3 Ajax.BeginForm Issue using jQuery Submit on Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome, c#-4.0

guys. I've been searching for an answer for my issue the whole morning, but I didn't have any success.

Here's the problem -> I have an Ajax.BeginForm which is submitted by a checkbox, using jquery:

```
    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Products",
                                                        new AjaxOptions
                                                        {
                                                            HttpMethod = "POST",
                                                            LoadingElementId = "divLoading",
                                                            UpdateTargetId = "divProducts"
                                                        }))
       {%>
       <%: Html.HiddenFor(mod => Model.ProductId) %>
    <%:Html.CheckBoxFor(mod => Model.ShowInactiveProducts,
                                              new
                                                  {
                                                      onchange =
                                                  "jQuery('#ShowInactiveProducts').closest('form').submit(); return false;"
                                                  })%> <%:Products_Resource.ShowInactive%>
    <%
       }%>
```

This code works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome it triggers the submit twice, where the first time the Request.IsAjaxRequest() returns true, and the second time it returns false.

I've read a lot of articles talking about unobstrusive Ajax and stuff, but none of them worked for me.

The funny part is that when I use an input-type-submit, it works like a charm...

Does anyone has any clue of what can I do to resolve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: remove the onchange attribute of the checkbox, and do it through jquery:

```
<script>
    $("#mycheckbox").change(function(){
    "jQuery('#ShowInactiveProducts').closest('form').submit();
    });
</script>
```

If this doesnt work, try creating a hidden submit button, and make the checkbox click it on change.

Comment: Although it's not the prettiest solution, the "plan B" worked! I made a hidden submit button! Thank you for the answer, I was so worried about making the ajax work in the right way that I forgot to think in a workaround!